# HELO Error when sending with Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

When I try to send a simple e-mail using Net.Mail.SmtpClient I get an error

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Access denied - Invalid
>   HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

The weird thing is that it works on my home computer, but not on the office computer.

Where or what can be the problem?

The code is written in VB.NET (.NET Framework 2.0):

```
Dim sendMail As New SmtpClient("mail.myhost.com", 25)
sendMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
sendMail.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("user@myhost.com", "123")
sendMail = New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.myhost.com", 25)
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail.From = New MailAddress("user@myhost.com", "Jack SMITH")
Dim maTO As MailAddress = New MailAddress("someone@gmail.com", "John DOE")
mail.To.Add(maTO)
mail.Subject = "The mail subject"
mail.Body = "The mail body"
mail.IsBodyHtml = False
sendMail.Send(mail)
mail.Dispose()
```

Comment: What does the erroneous HELO look like?

Comment: No direct experience with .NET but you see Windows computers using their locally configured name in HELO even though it's neither useful nor necessarily compatible with SMTP specifications. I'm guessing that's the problem here.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: RFC5321 defines a syntax for what the argument to HELO can be.  I'm guessing the Windows computer name (what you see in Desktop > My Computer > Properties, or it was there last time I used Windows) violates that spec.  But it's possible that the mail server has a content rule beyond or instead of a strict RFC5321 requirement.  Anyway, if you see `HELO \\localdomain\<3 Windows swearing @ú!%` then that's the problem.

Comment: Old but possibly useful: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/systemnetmailsmtpclient-fqdn-8906.aspx

Comment: Thank you, all! Turns out that when I disable SSL, it works..

Comment: That's not a very desirable workaround.  You should find a way to put a correct EHLO.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with this line: sendMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False

Comment: According to the linked discussion, you should be able to set `clientDomain` in the config file. What you should be setting it to is still a good question.