# Sending e-mail using Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

How can I send an e-mail using **Mozilla Thunderbird** from **vb.net**?

Does Thunderbird has an **API** or something like ***Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook*** for Outlook?

I've tried using command line '`-compose`' but it just opens the send new e-mail window in Thunderbird. I want to send it without any user interaction.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I'm not familiar with VB.net but the proper solution would seem to be to find an SMTP client library (and maybe a MIME library) you can call from your code

Comment: I have my reasons: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466101/helo-error-when-sendig-with-net-mail-smtpclient

Comment: Probably you could fix it by doing what Thunderbird and Outlook do: figure out the proper local SMTP server to use from the user's Internet preferences, then relay through that.  A possible additional benefit will be that you don't need to worry about the HELO name.

Comment: How do you solve this? I have the same problem.